How to automatically resolve schematic variables in records?
record r =
  ra :: nat
  rb :: nat
  rc :: nat

lemma blah1:
  assumes imp: "⋀r r' a'. Q r ⟹ r' = r ⦇ ra := a' ⦈ ⟹ P r'"
    and q: "Q x"
  shows "P x"
  apply (rule imp)
   (* proof goal: 
      1. Q ?r
      2. x = ?r⦇ra := ?a'⦈
   *)
   using q apply auto ― ‹Why can't Isabelle figure out x = x ⦇ ra := ?a' ⦈ ›
  oops

Instead, I have to tell it how to instantiate everything, which makes it pretty tedious.
lemma blah1_fixup:
  assumes imp: "⋀r r' a' b'. Q r ⟹ r' = r ⦇ ra := a' ⦈ ⟹ P r'"
    and q: "Q x"
  shows "P x"
  apply (rule imp[of x x "ra x"])
  using q by auto

